# What's the best way to make a difference-comparison between two (apparently) identical Raspberry Pis?

Tags: debugging, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault

So, I've been given a piece of software, originally written on a regular ol' laptop (running Ubuntu), and asked to see if I can get it running on a Raspberry Pi.

I've installed the software (and configured it) on two seemingly-identical Raspberry Pis running the same version of Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I've done the whole update/upgrade schtick on both multiple times.

The version of the software on each of the two Pis is the same, copied from the same flash drive, run on the same directory and with the same input parameters. They're both Pi model 2b, armV7r4, etc.

On one of them, the code runs properly, produces the expected output, and finishes up in about 2-minutes-twenty.

On the other, the code inevitably segfaults after about a minute twenty.

The code also compiles without issue on each.

The only apparent hardware difference I could spot between the two Pis is that one processor runs at about twice the BogoMIPS speed as the other one.

Can anyone suggest some likely comparisons I could make between the two devices to see if I can figure out what's causing it to miraculously work on one and not on the other?

Comment: `rpi-update` the firmware maybe?

Comment: `vcgencmd get_config` maybe?

Comment: Posted this just before going home yesterday, will try both and let you know my results.

Comment: Didn't run rpi-update b/c several sites said it was risky. Running vcgencmd produced identical output for each, except that the over_voltage_avs value was 0x124f8 on the not-working one and 0x23186 on the working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue I was working on was caused by residual, inaccessible files left over from a previous user I thought I'd thoroughly removed from the device.

When my software encountered them, it threw a fit and died.